# Why is a malformed function used instead of an implicit conversion?

Tags: c++, c++11, ambiguity, overload-resolution, malformed

This is my Snippet:

```
class Base{};

class Derived : private Base{};

template<class T>
class Wrapper
{
    public:
        template<typename T2>
        Wrapper( T2&& )
        { }
};

// Function declarations
void func( Base& param );
void func( Wrapper<Derived> );
void funcUnambiguous( Wrapper<Derived> );


// Here is the Call:
Derived d = Derived();  
func( d );               // <- Error
```

GCC 4.9 gives me: `error: 'Base' is an inaccessible base of 'Derived'`

Whereas I do

```
Derived d = Derived();

funcUnambiguous( d );
```

it just works fine.

It seems like, any function only requiring a cheap cast, even if malformed, hides implicit, but expensive-cast functions. Does anybody have clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated, thanks to @T.C.

`Wrapper`'s ctor is a <s>template</s> **user-defined conversion**, hence the <s>non-template</s> **standard conversion sequence** overload with `Base&` takes precedence. The access check is only performed *after* selecting the overload - which is too late in your case.

The complete rules are complicated, more can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), look at the section "Best viable function".

Comment: Even if malformed?! That does not really make sence, especially in this case, where the Base class is explicitely made "private".

Comment: I see, but isn't this a bug in the Standard? There is NO implicit conversion, not even an explicit. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JakobRiedle Overload resolution is one of the most complicated parts of C++ (IMHO). I wouldn't even dare to think that I know all rules in all cases, that I know what would be "right" or even "better" or how it all developed over time. :) I guess we'll just have to accept it as it is.

Comment: It's not template vs. non-template; that tiebreaker cannot distinguish between the two `func`s anyway because neither is a template. Derived-to-base conversion is considered a standard conversion sequence, which trumps a user-defined conversion sequence.